# A surjective linear map (T:E -> E) implies a bijective linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra

Prop.: Let T: E -> E be a linear mapping. If T is surjective, then T is injective.

I try to prove using that: If Tx = 0 implies x = 0, then T is injective. But it not work... Any help?

Comment: @ZacharySelk Sorry :( I'll delete this post. But thanks! That solved my problem

Comment: @ZacharySelk I don't know delete the post ;-;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivially if $T$ maps to the same domain ($E \rightarrow E$) and it is surjective (meaning that its imagespace is all of $E$.

By rank nullity theorem (and by extension the dimension theorem)
$$dim(Ker(T)) + dim(Im(T)) = dim(E)$$

Thus its kernel space must have dimension of $0$.

Comment: You might want to mention that your answer assumes that $ E $ is finite-dimensional, as this is not mentioned in the question.